# How to recreate an Auth0 user when relaunching app?

Tags: xamarin, auth0

I use Auth0 and refresh tokens in a Xamarin app.  If an ID token expires, I request one using the refresh token:

```
auth0 = new Auth0Client(AUTH0_DOMAIN, AUTH0_CLIENT_ID);
if (auth0.HasTokenExpired()) await auth0.RenewIdToken();
```

This works well, except I don't know what to do when the app restarts.  I can store the refresh token in the iPhone Keychain, but I don't know how to recreate an `Auth0User` from a refresh token.  The only way I can see to create an `Auth0User` is to log in again.  The documentation does not appear to address this.

How do I recreate a user when relaunching?

Comment: Did you ever discover the answer to this?

Comment: @LeighCiechanowski: No I gave up on Auth0.  I just couldn't get my questions answered, and their documentation was incomplete.  Maybe it's better now, since I think they received more funding.  I switched to Azure Active Directory B2C.